# Solve seems broken after I installed the package Tomatlab.m

Tags: equation-solving, packages

After I downloaded the *Mathematica* package [ToMatlab.m](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/577/), `Solve` does not work as before:

```
Solve[(x^2 + y^2)^(1/2) + ((x - a)^2 + (y - b)^2)^(1/2) == 2 l, y];
```

gives

> ```
> {{x -> Root[
>     b + y^20 #1 + (1 + 20 y^19) #1^2 + 190 y^18 #1^3 + 
>       1140 y^17 #1^4 + 4845 y^16 #1^5 + 15504 y^15 #1^6 + 
>       38760 y^14 #1^7 + 77520 y^13 #1^8 + 125970 y^12 #1^9 + 
>       167960 y^11 #1^10 + 184756 y^10 #1^11 + 167960 y^9 #1^12 + 
>       125970 y^8 #1^13 + 77520 y^7 #1^14 + 38760 y^6 #1^15 + 
>       15504 y^5 #1^16 + 4845 y^4 #1^17 + 1140 y^3 #1^18 + 
>       190 y^2 #1^19 + 20 y #1^20 + #1^21 &, 1]}, 
>  {x -> 
>    Root[b + y^20 #1 + (1 + 20 y^19) #1^2 + 190 y^18 #1^3 + 
>       1140 y^17 #1^4 + 4845 y^16 #1^5 + 15504 y^15 #1^6 + 
>       38760 y^14 #1^7 + 77520 y^13 #1^8 + 125970 y^12 #1^9 + 
>       167960 y^11 #1^10 + 184756 y^10 #1^11 + 167960 y^9 #1^12 + 
>       125970 y^8 #1^13 + 77520 y^7 #1^14 + 38760 y^6 #1^15 + 
>       15504 y^5 #1^16 + 4845 y^4 #1^17 + 1140 y^3 #1^18 + 
>       190 y^2 #1^19 + 20 y #1^20 + #1^21 &, 2]}, 
>  ...
>  {x -> 
>    Root[b + y^20 #1 + (1 + 20 y^19) #1^2 + 190 y^18 #1^3 + 
>       1140 y^17 #1^4 + 4845 y^16 #1^5 + 15504 y^15 #1^6 + 
>       38760 y^14 #1^7 + 77520 y^13 #1^8 + 125970 y^12 #1^9 + 
>       167960 y^11 #1^10 + 184756 y^10 #1^11 + 167960 y^9 #1^12 + 
>       125970 y^8 #1^13 + 77520 y^7 #1^14 + 38760 y^6 #1^15 + 
>       15504 y^5 #1^16 + 4845 y^4 #1^17 + 1140 y^3 #1^18 + 
>       190 y^2 #1^19 + 20 y #1^20 + #1^21 &, 21]}}
> ```

Sorry that I cannot use my installed version of *Mathematica* to show the output I got before I installed the package, because I cannot get the same output as before. But the output before installation is just as the normal `Solve` results, those from examples can be seen in the tutorial.

What's going on? And how can I fix this problem so that `Solve` works as before?

Comment: 1. What was the output of `Solve[]` before you loaded the package? 2. You should at least mention where you downloaded the package.

Comment: Look inside the .m file--does it have a Solve[] function defined within it?  If it does then this may be causing a naming conflict (I would try renaming it).

Comment: @Guess, Sorry for that I cannot use my MATHEMATICA to show the output before load the package, because I cannot get the same output as before. But the output before loading is just as the normal Solve[], whose examples can be seen in the tutorial

Comment: @Seb, I do not find a Solve[] function in the package, and I upload the links of the package in my question.

Comment: @Kylin Not sure then..  I would also look for possible naming conflicts with Root[.] since that is what is being returned unevaluated. Also, please provide the Solve[.] output that Guess requested. That can help localise the problem.

Comment: What you're supposed to do the next time you report incompatibilities: 1. close and reopen *Mathematica*; 2. execute your `Solve[]` instance and note the output; 3. load the offending package; 4. re-execute the `Solve[]` bit and note the output; 5. note the differences, and post them here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try clearing the variables first, for example:

```
Clear[a, b, x, y];
```

The result in the question can be reproduced exactly by evaluating

```
a = (x + y)^20 // Expand;
Solve[x^2 + a x + b == 0, x]
```

and the package example notebook [ToMatlabExamples.nb](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/577/ToMatlabExamples.nb?file_id=691) does contain such an assignment to `a` -- most likely it has been evaluated in the same kernel session before calling `Solve`.

Please see below and compare the different results obtained when `a` has that special value and when it doesn't.

[image]

This problem should not be persistent across kernel restarts, but just in case, you may want to evaluate `$UserBaseDirectory`, close *Mathematica*, and delete everything in that directory.

Comment: excuse me, I do not understand what is the meaning that " ToMatlabExamples.nb does contain such an assignment to a -- most likely it has been evaluated in the same kernel session before calling Solve". And   I have run the code `Clear[a, b, x, y];` and `a = (x + y)^20 // Expand;
Solve[x^2 + a x + b == 0, x]`, but the MATHEMATICA returns `{{x -> Root[
    b + y^20 #1 + (1 + 20 y^13 #1&, 1]},`

Comment: @Kylin I meant that `a` already had a value assigned (and the result you've shown indicates a most likely suspect ). Also note this is not the same `Solve` call as in the question but again, it must have been, based on the result. What do you get for `Information[a]`?

Comment: `a=x^20+20 x^19 y+190 x^18 y^2+1140 x^17 y^3+4845 x^16 y^4+15504 x^15 y^5+38760 x^14 y^6+77520 x^13 y^7+125970 x^12 y^8+167960 x^11 y^9+184756 x^10 y^10+167960 x^9 y^11+125970 x^8 y^12+77520 x^7 y^13+38760 x^6 y^14+15504 x^5 y^15+4845 x^4 y^16+1140 x^3 y^17+190 x^2 y^18+20 x y^19+y^20`

Comment: Your suggestion works! Thank u very much for yr prompt and patience. So the problem is that ToMatlab.nb has defined some `a`, right?

Comment: Yes, however to use that package only the `.m` file from the link is necessary, not the `.nb`.